# how should I declare nativeEvent when it is not the part of MouseEvent and KeyboardEvent property

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In my codebase, I have three interfaces which are `MouseEvent`, `KeyboardEvent` and `PointerEvent`.

And the list of properties for each interfaces match with the ones from these pages:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PointerEvent

However, when I try running a conditional statement with `nativeEvent` which is a property of `event` from the callback function, typescript displays error below:

```
Property 'pointerId' does not exist on type 'MouseEvent | KeyboardEvent'.
  Property 'pointerId' does not exist on type 'MouseEvent'.ts(2339)
```

If I changed its type to PointerEvent, then it displays another error which is

```
Property 'nativeEvent' does not exist on type 'PointerEvent | KeyboardEvent<Element>'.
  Property 'nativeEvent' does not exist on type 'PointerEvent'.ts(2339)
```

I also tried declaring `nativeEvent` inside the interface but also returns the error that it is not compatible.

```
Interface 'MouseEvent<T, E>' incorrectly extends interface 'UIEvent<T, E>'.
  Types of property 'nativeEvent' are incompatible.
```

`nativeEvent` is not listed as a property of `KeyboardEvent` and `MouseEvent`. In this case how am I supposed to declare type to use the conditional statement below?

```
  const onChange = (event: MouseEvent | KeyboardEvent) => {
    if (event.nativeEvent.pointerId) {
        onToggle();
      }
    }
  };
//
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are currently using the MouseEvent type that is Native. React has it's own MouseEvent type for TypeScript. You can utilize it by doing the following

```
const onChange = (event: React.MouseEvent | React.KeyboardEvent) => {
    if (event.nativeEvent.pointerId) {
        onToggle();
      }
    }
  };
```

I personally prefer instead of writing React. all over in the code to just import it as a type up at the top in your imports such as

```
import type { MouseEvent } from 'react';
```

Don't forget the type keyword that indicates that your import is being used as a type. Then you can just use MouseEvent as a type throughout that file like you have been. Hopefully, that helps!